# Finding and deleting last column with header if sum is 0

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro that finds the last column with a header and deletes it only if the sum of that column is equals to zero. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Dim LastCol As Long, Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
For i = Range("A1").Column To LastCol Step -1
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Application.Sum(Cells(1, i).Resize(LR, 1)) = 0 Then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete 
    End With
Next i
```

Thanks in advance for your attention and help

Comment: What happens when you run this? What error does it bring up if any ?

Comment: Your loop is backwards fam

Comment: Nothing happens when I run the code, I have no idea why

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim LastCol As Long, i As Long, LR As Long
    LR = 5
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = LastCol  to .Range("A1").Column Step -1
            If Application.Sum(.Cells(1, i).Resize(LR, 1)) = 0 Then
                .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what I have changed:

- Remove the 2. "Dim here -> Dim LastCol As Long, i As Long;
- Refer correctly to the `With` - `End with` - it is a good practice to have it, but it should be bringing you something - thus, you should put a dot before the ranges - `.Range("A1").Co..`, `.Columns(i).Entir...`, `.Cells(1, .Columns`
- You need `End If` at the end of the condition;
- Adding `[Option Explicit][1]` on top helps you find similar errors before running the code;
- You are refering to `lastcol` before assigning a value. Thus, it should go before the loop;
- The loop starts at column 1 and steps -1. It needs to be reversed (10x @Scott Craner);

Comment: Still not working, pal. One thing, the last collumn I'm trying to delete is filled with n/a for values, not zeroes.

Comment: One more thing, your code does delete my first column, which bears the rows' headers, not the last one